# Back button in multistep form

Tags: 7, forms

I am facing an issue with the [Multistep](https://www.drupal.org/project/multistep) module in Drupal 7. I used a custom module to build a *session_store* multistep form with the help of the [mforms_example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mforms/tree/mforms_example/mforms_example.module?id=9e56be352ae352d7cd8ca2a13cc797789a9cab89) module. Except for the **session_store_example** store key, other forms like *ajax_forms* and  *fs_store* have the back button implemented.

I tried to compare the form implementation of other storekey forms with the *session_store* form, but it didn't help.

Is there any way to add the *previous* button along with the *next* button in the *session_store_example* form?

Comment: you are naughty @Clive :)

Answer (score 0):

The first part may seem confusing, but we are just gathering what the user has picked before (in case they went to another portion of the form and came back here). Here we are doing the same thing as the other form, but now with two submit forms. One will bring you to the next form and one to the previous form.

```
/**
 * Form that is called second
 */
function multiform_second_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Make sure the default values for the checkboxes are set correctly.  
  if (!empty($form_state['storage'])) {
    $values = $form_state['storage'];
    if (!empty($form_state['storage']['food'])) {
      foreach ($form_state['storage']['food'] as $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
          $default_values[] = $value;
        }
      }
      if(empty($default_values)) {
        // Storage and experience are set, but no values were selected.
        $default_values = array();
      }
    }
    else {
      // Storage was set, but experience wasn't.
      $default_values = array();
    }
  }
  else {
    // Storage is not set.
    $default_values = array();
  }

  // Set options
  $checkboxes = array(
    1 => 'Pizza',
    2 => 'Hot Wings',
    3 => 'Subs',
    4 => 'Salads',
    5 => 'Garlic Bread',
    6 => 'Pasta',
    7 => 'Cake',
    8 => 'Ice Cream',
  );

  $form['additional'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['additional']['food'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Food you like'),
    '#options' => $checkboxes,
    '#default_value' => $default_values,
  );
  $form['additional']['company'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Company'),
    '#size' => 32,
    '#default_value' => isset($values['company']) ? $values['company'] : NULL,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['additional']['message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
    '#description' => t('Please provide information about your job'),
    '#size' => 32,
    '#default_value' => isset($values['message']) ? $values['message'] : NULL,
  );
  $form['back'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Back'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#submit' => array('multiform_second_form_submit'),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Next'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

for more details [custom multi step forms](http://bryanjones.us/article/custom-multi-step-forms-drupal-7)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this answer would be helpful only for independent custom module. I built the custom module which is dependent on [multistep module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multistep).

Comment: did you tried this https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_ajaxified_multipage

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `hook_form_alter()` Check the form id for your form and add the back button to it